# How set user specific price for a each user in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, selected, price

After admin approving the new user, the admin will be able to Show SELECTED products to each user. each user will be able to see only selected products only. The admin will assign user-specific prices for each product, each user will see his own prices.
Not for the user role. for each user(customer).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a readymade solution here is already an available plugin for that. There is a plugin available which offers you set price specific to a customer, customer or user role. You can increase or decrease the price based on quantities. It's a premium plugin which can be purchased from codecanyon from here.

[woocommerce customer specific user role group based pricing plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-customer-specific-user-role-group-based-pricing-plugin/23000223)

Comment: Thanks for replay, I got one plugin for a specific price for the user, but for my concept, not satisfy, so I customized plugin so problem fixed.